# [slam_toolbox]: Failed to compute odom pose leading to "No map received in Rviz"

Tags: ros2, rviz, slam, odometry, ros-iron

My team and I are currently working on an autonomous rover. I am using **ROS2 iron** with Ubuntu 22.04. Our rover is equipped with a **RPLIDAR** which is publishing on the ***/scan*** topic. We use this topic and a git package (https://github.com/dawan0111/Simple-2D-LiDAR-Odometry.git) which is providing us odometry via the ***/scan_odom*** topic. All of this as been tested multiple times and is working well. Then we wanted to add the mapping functionalities to our rover. I try using the **slam_toolbox** package from the great Steve Macenski. I added the **mapper_params_online_async.yaml** as follow :

```
slam_toolbox:
  ros__parameters:
    solver_plugin: solver_plugins::CeresSolver
    ceres_linear_solver: SPARSE_NORMAL_CHOLESKY
    ceres_preconditioner: SCHUR_JACOBI
    ceres_trust_strategy: LEVENBERG_MARQUARDT
    ceres_dogleg_type: TRADITIONAL_DOGLEG
    ceres_loss_function: None

    # ROS Parameters
    odom_frame: odom
    map_frame: map
    base_frame: base_footprint
    scan_topic: /scan
    mode: mapping #localization

    # if you'd like to start localizing on bringup in a map and pose
    #map_file_name: test_steve
    #map_start_pose: [5.0, 1.0, 0.0]

    debug_logging: false
    throttle_scans: 1
    transform_publish_period: 0.02 #if 0 never publishes odometry
    map_update_interval: 0.5
    resolution: 0.05
    max_laser_range: 20.0 #for rastering images
    minimum_time_interval: 0.5
    transform_timeout: 0.5
    tf_buffer_duration: 30.
    stack_size_to_use: 40000000 #// program needs a larger stack size to serialize large maps

    # General Parameters
    use_scan_matching: true
    use_scan_barycenter: true
    minimum_travel_distance: 0.5
    minimum_travel_heading: 0.5
    scan_buffer_size: 3
    scan_buffer_maximum_scan_distance: 10.0
    link_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.1  
    link_scan_maximum_distance: 1.5
    do_loop_closing: true 
    loop_match_minimum_chain_size: 3
    loop_match_maximum_variance_coarse: 3.0  
    loop_match_minimum_response_coarse: 0.35    
    loop_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.45

    # Correlation Parameters - Correlation Parameters
    correlation_search_space_dimension: 0.5
    correlation_search_space_resolution: 0.01
    correlation_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.1 

    # Correlation Parameters - Loop Closure Parameters
    loop_search_space_dimension: 8.0
    loop_search_space_resolution: 0.05
    loop_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.03
    loop_search_maximum_distance: 3.0

    # Scan Matcher Parameters
    distance_variance_penalty: 0.5      
    angle_variance_penalty: 1.0    

    fine_search_angle_offset: 0.00349     
    coarse_search_angle_offset: 0.349   
    coarse_angle_resolution: 0.0349        
    minimum_angle_penalty: 0.9
    minimum_distance_penalty: 0.5
    use_response_expansion: true
```

I also added the following node to my launch file in order to launch the slam_toolbox package :

```
slam = Node(
        package='slam_toolbox',
        executable='localization_slam_toolbox_node',
        name='slam_toolbox',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[slam_params_file,{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}],
    )
```

When I launch my script it works just as before, the map link  and the ***/map*** topic have been created but no information is being published on this ***/map*** topic (I echoed it), leading Rviz to display **"no map received"** : [image: Rviz]

odometry is still working but I get the error: **"[slam_toolbox]: Failed to compute odom pose"** : [image]

I can provide the tf tree : [image]

and also the rqt graph of my nodes : [image]

If someone as any idea of how we can overcome this issue we would be very thankfull

Comment: Please paste any code or console output as code formatted text and not as a screenshot. Screenshots are not text searchable, [amongst other things](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)...

Comment: Looking at the source code, that error is generated when trying to tansform odom and baselink. I suspect it has nothing to do with the map. Possible you have two different issues. It is very common for the map issues to be caused by QOS settings and misunderstanding about when the map gets published.  I suggest verifying TF names are consistent and evaluation of the source code. https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox/blob/ros2/include/slam_toolbox/get_pose_helper.hpp